# Hidden columns taking space on Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I am working on a SSRS report and depending on column selection from user page, have to show/hide some of the columns. I am using expression on field value

```
=IIf(Fields!CatalogueDescription.Value = "[-HIDE-]",false,true)
```

when report appears it shows wide space for columns hidden which is not right. Also when I tried to right click on SSRS tablix design time, the column visiblity... option is disabled, why, have no idea. How can I hide columns in such way without leaving blank/white space?

Comment: do you have that on the field visibility expression or is that on the column visibility expression.

Comment: I tried on both column header and detail. I am using Tablix

Comment: Ok so I was doing some playing around and it looks like you may have your iif statement backward. The visibility property is a little backward depending on how you have the initial visibility of that column set. The visibility boolean is the toggle of visibility. So if the initial visibility is true and your visibility boolean is true then the toggle flips and visibility is set to false. It is not just simply visible "true" or "false. Check the initial visibility of your column and change your boolean accordingly. Also make sure that you are setting this expression in the Column visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.

On Tablix, right click on column and select visibility... and on expression use something like

=Fields!CatalogueDescription.Value = "[-HIDE-]"

Remember here it takes false to hide it. Or try your Boolean values and it will work for sure.

Comment: What is "[-HIDE-]"?  Is there a list somewhere of these secret values you can check for?

Comment: It could be just a static value/indicator set by user in recordset for report, user can set these values if want to display or not. In report you can set expression for report to display or hide.

Comment: I want the column to be shown/hid dynamically.  I don't think I was clear on that.  So regardless of what the value of the column is.  From what I've read elsewhere there is no easy way to do this, just a shortcoming of SSRS.